# I want to create a new csv from the existing csv consist of multiple same columns but not sorted data

Tags: r

I have a CSV with these data:

```
 List  Rank.A  List   Rank.B  List  Rank.C
   a      4      a      8      b      3
   b      5      e      5      e      9
   c      7      f      5      r      1
```

I want to create a new csv in which there is only a one-column with a name **List** with a unique value and there is 3 more columns of "Rank.A", "Rank.B", "Rank.C" in same list. Suppose if Rank.A not listed with any row of List than it display blank. I want data in this format

```
List    Rank.A    Rank.B    Rank.C
  a       4         8      
  b       5                   3
  c       7      
  e                 5         9
  f                 5
  r                           1
```

Can you please help me in that?

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `split.default` (to split your `data.frame` by columns) and `Reduce` + `merge` to combine data into a single `data.frame`.

```r
Reduce(
    function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE),
    split.default(df, rep(1:(ncol(df) / 2), each = 2)))
#    List Rank.A Rank.B Rank.C
#  1    a      4      8     NA
#  2    b      5     NA      3
#  3    c      7     NA     NA
#  4    e     NA      5      9
#  5    f     NA      5     NA
#  6    r     NA     NA      1
```

Note that this assumes that you always have pairs of columns (`List`, `Rank.x`) in your original data.

---

### Sample data

```r
df <- read.table(text =
"List  Rank.A  List   Rank.B  List  Rank.C
   a      4      a      8      b      3
   b      5      e      5      e      9
   c      7      f      5      r      1", header = T, check.names = F)
```